# How to Update a table from another tables Insert script in Azure backend

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Xamarin.Forms mobile app using Azure Easy Tables setup and working for all CRUD operations.  I now need some node.js server-side functionality which will enable me to update increase a column's count in tableB from an insert script on tableA. i.e. where tableB.someId = tableA.someId

So far I have:

```
// INSERT into tableA
table.insert(function(context) {

logger.info('Running tableA.insert');

// get tableB
var tableB = azureMobileApps.tables.table('tableB');

// here i need to increase the noOfReviews column on tableB by one
............
```

I'm a complete starter to Azure node.js, can anyone help?

Iain

Answer (score 1):

You can load up records from other tables with something similar to the following:

```
table.insert(function (context) {
    var tableB = context.tables('tableB');
    var tableBRecords = tableB.where({ id: 'someId' }).read()
        .then(function (records) {
            records[0].count++;
            return tableB.update(records[0]);
        })
        .then(context.execute);
});
```

You can find API documentation for the context object at http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#context.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think you can try to execute custom SQL statements to implement for increasing the tableB column which value count the related column in tableA, please see refer to the section "How to: Execute custom SQL statements" of the article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#CustomAPI.